# Shutil.copy: Why is my script looking for unicode instead of the path saved in my variable?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy, shutil, os.path

I'm trying to use the shutil module to copy files from one drive to another.  Since this is an ArcGIS script, I store the user's choice for folder source and destination locations as:

```
src = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
dst = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
```

Using arcpy.AddMessage(src) to print that out gives me:

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\File.extension
```

Which is what I want! However, when I try to use shutil.copy(src,dst), I get:

```
u'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\File.extension'

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'C:\\Folder1\\Folder2'
```

What is happening here? Since I'm not spelling out the path I can't change the "u" to an "r" for raw input...

Comment: your chasing red herrings ... the unicode string is certainly not your problem ...

Comment: Is it a glaring problem I'm missing?

Comment: likely that the folder doesnt exists ... (even though windows is not case-sensitive with filepaths, shutil might be...)  I would need to see more of your code ... my my guess is that you have a simple typo somewhere

Comment: You're right -- file didn't exist. I'm using a for loop to join file names to the path and then copy to new folder, and the sample file name I was using didn't exist. Thanks Joran

Answer (score 0):

Shutil.copy/unicode wasn't the problem here; tyring to copy a non-existent file was.

Answer (score 0):

As a form of file management validation, you should always check to see whether or not the directory exists.  You can do this using the os.path.exists(path) method. If your path exists, you should have no problem. If not, then create it before copying your files over.

See example code below:

```
if not os.path.exists(dst):
    os.mkdir(dst)

shutil.copy(src, dst)
```